# filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, filter

I am doing FreeCodeCamp javascript. I supposed to get the output with an array that include all of the own properties of an object.

```
function Bird(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.numLegs = 2;
}

let canary = new Bird("Tweety");

let ownProps = canary.filter(prop => canary.hasOwnProperty(prop))
```

When I executes this I got : filter is not function error.

Comment: `canary` is an object. and `filter` is method of arrays.

Comment: You have no arrays in your question, and `Bird` has no `filter` method

Comment: @CertainPerformance But I construct an instance canary to Bird, right. Now canary is an Object, isn't it.

Comment: @MaheerAli so, can't we use filter over objects?

Comment: No we can't. because there is nothing like `Object.prototype.filter`. But if you want to remove some `key:value` from object you can use `Object.entries()` on object to get array and then use `filter()` on that. But in your case you don't need that because there is built in function for your need.

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka, I am curious, would you mind sharing the link to the FreeCodeCamp that is telling you to do it this way.

Comment: @Daniel actually FCC don't gave me any way to proceed. At that time I am a noob (still learning), so I don't know that filter is not for an object. Thank you for information also.

Comment: @MohanKumarsajjamoka, no worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canary` which is instance of `Bird` is an object and object doesnot have any method called `filter()`. If you want to get all properties of an object use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`

```js
function Bird(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.numLegs = 2;
}

let canary = new Bird("Tweety");

let ownProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(canary);

console.log(ownProps)
```

Answer (score 1):

You utilized what in object-oriented programming is called an **object constructor** to create the object `canary`, it uses the `new` keyword and it's one of two ways of creating an object in JavaScript. The other way being the utilization of `{}` which is known as an **object literal**.

Anyway, next comes the understanding of *array helper methods* such as `filter()`, notice it's an *array* helper method. You cannot run `filter()` on an object which you initialized `canary` as when you did this:

```
let canary = new Bird("Tweety");
```

I know the error "filter is not a function" does not make that clear, but it's basically telling you "hey this is an object that you are trying to run an array helper function on", hence, *filter is not a function* (for an object).